# What provides install on alpine?

Tags: alpine-linux

When I try to `apk add install`, the package can't be found

```
  install (no such package):
    required by: world[install]
```

What utility provides /bin/install?

Answer (score 2):

The Busybox install is installed by default. It's available as `/usr/bin/install`. If you want GNU install that's packaged under `coreutils`

```
apk add coreutils
```